# Simulating a Jump with keyDown Glut C++ not 100%

Tags: c++, glut

I'm controlling a sprite on screen using `glutkeyboardfunc` and `keyDown`'s.

Eg. When I implement the following code the sprite successfully jumps up:

```
 if(keyDown[119]){//w key = up
    sprite_y +=40.0f;
    spriteT=spriteJ;
 }
```

Whilst in the air, the sprite returns using this code:

```
 if(sprite_y>0){ gravity-=10*delta; sprite_y+=gravity; }
 else{ gravity=0; }
```

The problem I'm having is, if you keep your finger down on the `w` key, the sprite jumps forever and keeps going up.

I understand this is because I'm using the `keyDown` method so I tried this:

```
 if(keyDown[119]){//w key = up
    sprite_y +=40.0f;
    spriteT=spriteJ;
    keyDown[119]=0;//reset keyDown to keyUp
 }
```

But I had no luck...

Is there a way I can limit the `keyDown` to a certain time period or only act as if it was pressed once? Thanks.

**edit** I dont quite understand how this question is worthy of a vote down. Did you even read it?

Comment: Are those snipets within the same function or class? Because you need a additional variable to store the information "already jumped", so you won't jump again.

Comment: They are all within the same function at the moment. I hadnt considered that...

Comment: In that case the simplest solution (if you don't need the information elsewhere) can be to add a static variable to that function, initializized with false. you can even give it a nicer name like "hang_time" or "airborne" or similar.. :)

Comment: Ok thanks for your time. I really apprciate it. I will give it a go :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to represent the previous state of the key, and then see if it has changed.

For example:

```
//Initialise a bool called keyWasDown to false

if (keyDown[119]){
    if (!keyWasDown){
        //Do jumping code
        keyWasDown = true;
    }
else {
    keyWasDown = false;
}
```